# f is a differentiable function. Which of the limits is equal to f′(a)?

Tags: derivatives

here are the options:
$$\begin{align*}
 \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+8h)-f(a-5h)}{-2h}
\end{align*}$$
$$\begin{align*}
 \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+1h)-f(a-9h)}{-4h}
\end{align*}$$
$$\begin{align*}
 \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+3h)-f(a-9h)}{1h}
\end{align*}$$
$$\begin{align*}
 \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+3h)-f(a-8h)}{11h}
\end{align*}$$

I am blank and i am not able approach this question. Please explain each of the steps you apply while you solve.

Comment: Use $f(x) = x$ with $a=0$. It becomes obvious that the first three fail immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then
$$
f(a+\lambda)\approx f(a)+f'(a)\,\lambda.
$$
In each case, take appropriate values for $\lambda$.

Comment: Much better than the L'Hospital's Rule approach one might suggest.

Comment: Not to mention that L'Hopital wouldn't work unless $f$ is continuously differentiable near $a.$

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is defined as

\begin{align*}
 \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{f(a+k)-f(a)}{k}
\end{align*}

Of all your examples look at
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+3h)-f(a-8h)}{11h}
\end{align*}
and replace $a + 3h$ by $b - 8h$ so that $a+ 3h$ = $b+ 11h$ then this gives
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(b+11h)-f(b)}{11h}
\end{align*}
Now replace $11 h$ by $k$, so that you have
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{f(b+k)-f(b)}{b}
\end{align*}
so this is the derivative evaluated at $a, /,f'(a)$ (since as $k \to 0, b \to a$). You must evaluate the function at two points that are close to each other, say at $a$ and $a + k$ and divide by the same value. If you used the same approach for your first possibility you would get
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+8h)-f(a-5h)}{-2h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(b+13h)-f(b)}{-2h}
\end{align*}
This is equal to $-13/2 \, f'(a)$